# Package for Finite Automata similar to this image

Tags: beamer, tikz-styles, automata

In some beamer slides I found several finite automata similar to this one:

[image]

How to reproduce that style in Latex? Which package and configuration I should set?

TikZ should be the way to go, but actually I didn't found any configuration to obtain **exactly** the same style. Maybe I have not checked the documentation deeply enough.

EDIT:

A minimal working example using TikZ, replicating the automaton in the figure above:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto] 
    \node[state,initial] (0)   {$0$}; 
    \node[state,accepting](1) [right=of 0] {$1$};
    \path[->] 
    (0) edge  node {$G$} (1)
        edge [loop above] node {not $G$} (0)
    (1) edge [loop above] node {true} (1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: If your problem is that you cannot find any configuration with the exact same style, maybe you could add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) with another style which we then could tweak to resemble your image?

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right, I've just added a MWE and the generated image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the tool that generates the automaton in the question with exactly the same style is [OmniGraffle](https://www.omnigroup.com/omnigraffle/), a software for Mac only. Hence, it is not a Latex package.

You can find another example below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to TeX.SE! It is rather simple to cook up something similar.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning,shadows.blur}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto,font=\sffamily] 
    \node[state,blur shadow,fill=white] (0)   {$0$}; 
    \node[state,accepting,blur shadow,fill=white](1) [right=of 0] {$1$};
    \draw[thick,latex-] (0.210) -- ++(210:0.5);
    \draw[thick,rounded corners=3mm,-latex](0.north) -- ++(135:1) -- ++(-135:1) 
    node[midway,above left]{not G}  -- (0.west);
    \draw[thick,rounded corners=3mm,-latex](1.east) -- ++(45:1) -- ++(150:1) 
    node[midway,above right]{true}-- (1.north);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I'm looking for a package or TkiZ theme that cope with all the details of your code (I don't know if it already exists and how it's called). Your code is really helpful, indeed it answers the part of the question "similar to this image". Unfortunately, it seems too low level to use your hints for a bigger automaton.

Comment: @MarcoFavorito I do not know if such a package exists. However, the nice thing about Ti*k*Z is that you can define and modify your own styles. That is, you only have to redefine `state` to also drop a shadow and so on. Then you do not have to repeat these things.

Comment: Oh, I see! Thank you, it will definitely be helpful!